# Rscript not closing connections to stdin

Tags: r

I have an Rscript that allows text input by the user when run on the command line.
The code is this:

```
f <- file("stdin")
open(f)
response <- readLines(f, n = 1L)
close(f)
```

However, after a certain number of interactions, the script exits, with the error message --

> Error in open.connection(f) : cannot open the connection
>   
>  Calls: open -> open.connection
>   
>  In addition: Warning message:
>   
>  In open.connection(f) : cannot open file 'stdin': Too many open files
>   
>  Execution halted

I thought that with `close()` I would be closing the connection to `stdin`, but clearly I'm doing something wrong and would be grateful for any help. Here's a reproducible example with the 'iris' dataset (for me it fails at row 253):

```
iristest <- rbind(iris, iris)
for (r in 1:nrow(iristest)) {
    print(paste("Iris row:", r))
    print(iristest[r,])
    print("Press any key to continue")
    f <- file("stdin")
    open(f)
    response <- readLines(f, n = 1L)
    close(f)
}
```

thanks in advance, Andrew

Comment: It is not reproducible on my system (OS X 10.10.5, R 3.2.2, using cmd-line R console). Can you post the output of `devtools::session_info()`?

Comment: thank you @hrbrmstr for trying it. I'm also on OS X 10.10.5, R 3.2.2 and using cmd-line R console.

Comment: and @hrbmstr, the output of devtools::session_info() is an error message: "cannot open compressed file '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rstudioapi/Meta/package.rds', probable reason 'Too many open files'"

Comment: take a look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108174/how-to-persist-ulimit-settings-in-osx-mavericks to change your `ulimit`s